# SQL Cast String field to XML slow

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, casting, xquery

I have a table in MS SQL with a field that contain a string that rappresent an XML like this:

```
        < Root >
           < Value_Tab2 ID = "182" >    
               < Value_Tab3 >
                   < Value > 1219 </ Value > 
              </ Value_Tab3 >
           </ Value_Tab2 >
           < Value_Tab2 ID = "187" >
               < Value_Tab3 >
                   < Value > 3192 </ Value >
               </ Value_Tab3 >
           </ Value_Tab2 >
        </ Root >
```

I can query this field casting string as XML but, with 50000 rows of MyTable1, query take 7-8 second. The query I use is this:

```
        SELECT MT1.ID
            ,cast(MT1.StringXml as xml).value('(Root/Value_Tab2/@ID)[1]', 'INT') AS MT1_ID1
            ,cast(MT1.StringXml as xml).value('(Root/Value_Tab2/@ID)[2]', 'INT') AS MT1_ID2
            ,cast(MT1.StringXml as xml).value('(Root/Value_Tab2/Value_Tab3/Value)[1]', 'INT') AS VALUE_ID1
            ,cast(MT1.StringXml as xml).value('(Root/Value_Tab2/Value_Tab3/Value)[2]', 'INT') AS VALUE_ID2
        FROM MyTable1 MT1 with (NOLOCK)
        WHERE MT1.Published = 1
```

StringXML is MyTable1 filed as nvarchar(MAX); is this the correct way to query a string field and cast as XML?

Thare are other way or workaround to improve query performance?

Comment: Why you need to do it in SQL? Can you load whole string and deserialize with technologies designed for such purpose (some of programming languages)?

Comment: Because I need MT1_ID and MT1_ID2 in the query to feach result.

Comment: You're casting that field *multiple* times. If you want to store XML in that field, why not change its type to `xml` and possibly index it as well? **Especially** if you want to extract specific parts. What you do now is slower than the slowest way possible

Comment: I can't change the table.

Comment: Then you lose. Using the wrong types means you'll always have performance and conversion problems. One thing you could do to improve things slightly is to use a CTE or subquery to cast to XML and put the XQuery transformations in the outer query.

Comment: Another thing is to remove `NOLOCK` immediately. This doesn't mean `don't take locks` or `go fast`, it means `produce bad or duplicate data while taking excessive locks and throw at random`.

Comment: If those values are used frequently you can convert the expressions to persisted computed columns and even index them. Check [Promote Frequently Used XML Values with Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/promote-frequently-used-xml-values-with-computed-columns?view=sql-server-ver15). You can create functions that parse the field as XML and extracts the values you want

Comment: BTW 50K rows is no data at all. Even if SQL Server scans the entire table as it does now, to find the rows and extract the values, 8 seconds is too much. There are other problems involved in this. Is this query used inside another bigger query perhaps? Is the *real* table far larger than 50K perhaps? If `Published` is a bit, or an `int` that only takes two values, the selectivity is so bad it would be cheaper for SQL Server to scan the entire table to find matches than use an index that simply splits the rows in two big buckets

Comment: Yes, it's a part of query but if I run only this pice of code it take 7 sec for 50k rows. Publish is a bit.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is called XML shredding.

Please try the following.

As @PanagiotisKanavos already pointed out, the CAST operation is done just once. All XPath expressions are optimized for performance.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, Published BIT, StringXml NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @tbl (Published, StringXml) VALUES
(1, N'<Root>
    <Value_Tab2 ID="182">
        <Value_Tab3>
            <Value>1219</Value>
        </Value_Tab3>
    </Value_Tab2>
    <Value_Tab2 ID="187">
        <Value_Tab3>
            <Value>3192</Value>
        </Value_Tab3>
    </Value_Tab2>
</Root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ID, Published
        , TRY_CAST(StringXml AS XML) AS xmldata
    FROM @tbl
)
SELECT ID, c.value('Value_Tab2[1]/@ID', 'INT') AS MT1_ID1
    , c.value('Value_Tab2[2]/@ID', 'INT') AS MT1_ID2
    , c.value('(Value_Tab2[1]/Value_Tab3/Value/text())[1]', 'INT') AS VALUE_ID1
    , c.value('(Value_Tab2[2]/Value_Tab3/Value/text())[1]', 'INT') AS VALUE_ID2
FROM rs
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/Root') AS t(c)
WHERE rs.Published = 1;
```

**Output**

```
+----+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| ID | MT1_ID1 | MT1_ID2 | VALUE_ID1 | VALUE_ID2 |
+----+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |     182 |     187 |      1219 |      3192 |
+----+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```